# How to switch the movement and camera controls?

Tags: max-payne-3

In Max Payne 3 (for Xbox 360), my movement and camera controls are switched from what I expect. In most other games the right stick is movement and the left stick is the camera, but in Max Payne 3 the left stick is movement and the right stick is the camera. What can I do to change that?

Comment: That sounds normal for most games.  Are you sure that's even something you can change?

Answer (score 1):

Look in the gamepad options for "Southpaw", that toggles the two gamepad sticks.